# Add an “exclude module” rule to an entry in plugin.xml for Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm stucking with this error trying to build my phonegap project

[image]
As far I know this error because there is a library is set twice in the project.
I check all my libraries and I found only one library causing this(found in one of my plugins)

```
 <framework src="com.android.support:design:23.4.0"/>
```

The thing is, can I set an exclude module rule in the plugin.xml file?
I think I need to exclude com.android.supportv4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I resolved it, I had to create a build-extras.gradle file in my plugin containing the following lines:

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'}
```

Then this gradle file need to imported in plugin.xml file using:

```
<framework src="build-extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

Comment: Nice discovery! In which directory of your plugin did you create the build-extras.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release which is a "plugin to align various versions of the Android Support libraries specified by other plugins".

They use a [clever gradle dependency resolution](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/blob/master/cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle#L27) to solve the problem:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group in ['com.android.support'] && !(details.requested.name in ['multidex', 'multidex-instrumentation'])) { details.useVersion "26.1.0"}
    }
}
```

This avoids the problem of removing *all* Android support libs, which can lead plugins having missing dependencies/failing gradle syncs.